# Is $\mathbb{N}$ a well-founded set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, infinity, natural-numbers

I was reading about Von Neumann's construction of $\mathbb{N}$, I understood that $\mathbb{N}=\{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}, \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\},...\} $.
I see that, with this construction, $\mathbb{N}$ has an infinite descending membership sequence. My question is, does this mean that $\mathbb{N}$ is not well founded? If yes, what are the consequences?
Thanks.

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by $\infty$?

Comment: @AndresCaicedo By $\infty$ I mean $\left\{\emptyset,\left\{\emptyset\right\}, \left\{\left\{\emptyset,\left\{\emptyset\right\}\right\}\right\},...\right\}$ , which as I mentionned can be seen as the 'limit' (?) of the successor's application.

Comment: Why do you think the set is not well-founded?

Comment: Because it has an infinite descending membership sequence.

Comment: @ZakariaDza: Which is?

Comment: @AsafKaragila sorry, I edited my question :)

Comment: @Zakaria: Asaf isn't being snarky: try actually writing down the infinite descending membership sequence. Either you'll quickly realize the problem, or you're actually thinking about an infinite *ascending* membership sequence.

Comment: Zakaria: That is a completely different question, and it completely nullifies my answer. You should have asked a whole new one, instead of editing this one. But @Hurkyl just answered your new question, so no point in doing so.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remember that the relation on $\Bbb R$ (let alone, any set extending it) is **not** the $\in$ relation.

Since well-foundedness only requires $\in$ to be well-founded, there is no issue here.

---

This set that you mention is usually denoted by $\omega$, the first infinite ordinal. It has nothing to do with $\Bbb R$. The "natural numbers" as we perceive them in $\Bbb R$ and the "natural numbers" as finite ordinals are two completely different arithmetical systems. One of real numbers and the other of ordinals (or cardinals, which is a third system).

The $\infty$ that we think about in calculus is not an ordinal, or a cardinal. It is a formal notion of something which exists "at the end of the line". You can use $\omega$, or any other set in your universe to represent this $\infty$, but this representation is not going to matter, since the way in which we mean that $\infty\in\overline{\Bbb R}$ is related to the topology of $\Bbb R$, rather than to the $\in$ relation, which defines the order on the ordinals (and cardinals).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, It partially answers my question, but my question was not well worded.